# Magento API: Requested payment method is not available

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I’m working on an interface between Amazon and Magento. I want to get all orders from Amazon and display them in my Magento orders list. All works fine till I reach the point where I have to set the payment method. No matter which payment method I choose, every time I get this error:

> “Requested payment method is not available”

But this payment method is available (it's active). Any customer can use it on the original checkout page and it works. In the configuration the payment method is activated and available for each customer group.

```
$this->soap->shoppingCartPaymentMethod($this->getSessionID(), $cartID, array("method" => "banktransfer"));
```

For the field method, I tried banktranser, ccsave, and paypal_standard. None of them worked.

Any ideas? Do you need more information?